# Looking for an open-source Java Help API

Tags: java, api, open-source, chm

I'm working on an application written in Java.
I want to allow the user to read the "Help" of the application.

I'm basically looking for a **Java free open-source** equivalent for Microsoft chm.
I'd like it to have support for "Find" and tree-like structures.

I am willing to write one component myself but I was wondering if existent alternatives already existed before attempting to reinvent the wheel...

Are there any options available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [JavaHelp](https://javahelp.dev.java.net/), defined by [JSR 97](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=97).

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at http://www.pdfhelp.org which offers a free PDF based alternative?